# Trouble with Observable and http json Angular

Tags: json, angular, http, observable

I have a problem because I never draw the variable "datos" in the * nFor,
I think the problem is in the render, 
for this reason implements "Observable", however it still does not work

Thanks for help!

"header-menu.component.ts"

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Component({
        moduleId: module.id,
        selector: 'as-headermenu',
        templateUrl: 'header-menu.html',
        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })

    export class HeaderMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    datos = []; // Aqui se carga el json
    private ruta = 'assets/json_header_menu.json';  

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    ngOnInit() {
         this.loadJson().subscribe(
                    vdatos => this.datos = vdatos,
                    err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log(this.datos));
        console.log(this.datos);
    }

loadJson(): Observable<any[]> {
          return this.http.get(this.ruta)
            .map(res => res.json());
}
}
```

"header-menu.html"

```
<ul *ngIf="datos"> <li *ngFor="let dato of datos | async; let i =
index"> {{ dato.url }} {{ dato.icono }} {{ dato.titulo }} {{ i }} 
</li>
```

"header-menu-module.ts"

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { HeaderMenuComponent } from './index';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HeaderMenuComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    exports: [
        HeaderMenuComponent
    ]
})
export class HeaderMenuModule {
}
```

Image Console error:[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2R9R.png)

Comment: try removing the async pipe (| async)

Comment: As addition, that you should indeed remove the async pipe (or don't use subscribe) Seems from your error message where you have console logged your response (I assume) and it shows `[ ]` so it would be empty?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the async pipe here, it should work without it,

```
<ul *ngIf="datos"> <li *ngFor="let dato of datos; let i =
index"> {{ dato.url }} {{ dato.icono }} {{ dato.titulo }} {{ i }} 
</li>
```

Comment: just use ngOnInit() {
      this.datos = this.loadJson();
 }

Answer (score 1):

`| async` pipe does help to unwrap your data from `Observable` stream. So to make your code work you should assign observable to `datos` variable.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.datos = this.loadJson();
}
```

Comment: When i change datos to: datos: Observable<any[]>;   and assign   this.datos = this.loadJson().subscribe(
                vdatos => this.datos = vdatos,
                err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log(this.datos)); <br> I get the error :  Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>   please help  Mr. Pankaj Parkar

Comment: @SantiagoMatiz check my answer.. It should not have part after `.subscribe`.. `ngOnInit` will only have `this.datos = this.loadJson();`

Answer (score 0):

I fix it removing the line of code "changeDetection"

```
 @Component({
        moduleId: module.id,
        selector: 'as-headermenu',
        templateUrl: 'header-menu.html',
        /*changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush*/
    })
```

thanks